# Sqlite, SELECT DISTINCT get multiple last rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

Just can't figure out what's wrong with this SQLite query.

I have ACCOUNTS table like this

```
subscr_id,txn_type,PAYMENT_START
A,        signup,  1
A,        pay,     2
A,        pay,     3
A,        cancel,  4
B,        signup,  1
B,        pay,     2
B,        pay,     3
```

and i want to output `A,cancel,4` and `B,pay,3`, (only last value ordered by time (PAYMENT_START) for each unique subscr_id)

```
SELECT DISTINCT subscr_id,
   LAST_VALUE(txn_type) OVER (
   PARTITION BY subscr_id ORDER BY PAYMENT_START asc
   RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
) AS last FROM ACCOUNTS;
```

When i want to execute this i get error:

Error: near "(": syntax error

Comment: Perhaps your version of SQLite doesn't support window functions.

Comment: I will check that, but in mean time is there other way to select last value for each subscr_id?

Comment: Window function support was first added to SQLite with release version `3.25.0` (2018-09-15). The SQLite developers used the PostgreSQL window function documentation as their primary reference for how window functions ought to behave. Many test cases have been run against PostgreSQL to ensure that window functions operate the same way in both SQLite and PostgreSQL. My sqlite3 version is `3.13.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `payment_start` is not repeated for a given subscriber, you can do what you want using a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*
from accounta a
where a.payment_start = (select max(a2.payment_start)
                         from accounts a2
                         where a2.subscr_id = a.subscr_id
                        )
```

Comment: I just upgraded sqlite3 to 3.32.3 and LAST_VALUE is working. Tank you for your time.